# Connection to Microsoft FTP server hangs when transferring thousands of files

Tags: ftp, iis, lftp

I am seeing that some ftp clients cannot complete when transferring thousands of files to an FTP server. The `mput *` command runs for several hours and then hangs
in

```
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
```

I do not have an easy way to contact the FTP server administrators (all I have is an IP address in the block managed by `WeHostWebSites.Com` and I know that this IP is shared by a dozen of domain names).

The FTP server introduces itself as

```
220 Microsoft FTP Service
```

So I assume it is IIS.

I am running an `mput *` on a directory that contains thousands of files. Until the transfer hangs for a while, until the control connection is closed for inactivity.

Having examined the logs I see the following pattern. Initially the files are transferred in **passive** mode.

```
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||53567|)
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
```

Then the port numbers increase until they reach 65200. At this point the server returns `501`.

```
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||65201|)
501 Server cannot accept argument.
```

Which triggers the clients such as `lukemftp` (that comes by default with OpenSUSE 11 installations) or FAR manager FTP plugin (which is popular with Windows users) to switch to **active** so the following transfers start with the `PORT` command.

```
200 PORT command successful.
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection.
```

`netstat -t` also shows that new connections go to port 20/tcp of the server. After transferring another 3000+ files the command hangs. At this point the output from `netstat -t` shows how `TIME_WAIT` connections drain and then the control connection is closed for inactivity.

**Workaround:** It is often suggested to use `lftp` for large FTP transfers and this proved to be a way round the problem. Watching `lftp` executing a `mirror -R` command on a directory with 100000+ files I can see how the dynamic port numbers run up to 65200 and then continue from 49152 keeping all transfers in passive. So this command completes successfully.

Is there a way to work around this problem without the use of `lftp` (In particular, what could be done on a purely Windows client that does not have `lftp`?

**Notice:** This question was posted several months ago on http://serverfault.com but did not receive any answers and a recent close vote. I decided to remove it from ServerFault and repost it on SuperUser instead.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a `on access antivirus-software` or `continous backup software` on the server? Maybe disabling it for testing purposes changes something.

Think of the following process:

1. `put` file from ftp-client to server
2. server opens stream to temporary file
3. antivirus-software or backup-software locks the (temporary) file for scanning or backup
4. while scanning the temporary file the ftp-server wants to `move` the finished file to its final location and name
5. since the file is locked at this moment the final operation could fail and throw an error.

Comment: I guess this `move` failure would be somehow reflected in the server log. So the key thing is to get hold of the server logs, right?

Comment: yes. consult the eventlog and the ftp-log. If you haven't already done, switch on extensive logging for the ftp-service.